# Rails rack attack gem throttle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rackattack

I don't know why I can not use rack-attack gem
Here what I did

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'rack-attack'
```

I ve installed the gem

**config/application.rb**

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Attack
```

**initializers/rack-attack.rb**

```
class Rack::Attack

throttle('logins/ip', :limit => 5, :period => 60.seconds) do |req|
  if req.path == '/login' && req.post?
  Rails.logger.error("Rack::Attack Too many login attempts from IP: #{req.ip}")
  req.ip 
  end
end

end
```

**routes.rb**

```
post   'login'   => 'index#create'
root 'index#new'
get 'login' => 'index#new'
```

I am using Rails 4.2.3 and the rack-attack gem 4.3.0

I wonder what I miss

Comment: here too. +1. won't work out of the box in development

Answer (score 9):

make sure you configure **cache.store** in your initializers/rack-attack.rb file
you can configure it like that:

```
class Rack::Attack
  ...
  cache.store = ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore.new
  ...
end
```

Comment: Using `Rack::Attack.cache.store = ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore.new` might also work for some

Answer (score 0):

[You may need enable the cache in your development environment](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack#testing)

please set `config.cache_classes = true` in `config/environments/development.rb`.

Comment: doesn't work even after enabling cache_class= true in development.rb

Comment: cache_classes is for class loading, not for the cache store.

From Rails documentation:
config.cache_classes controls whether or not application classes and modules should be reloaded if they change. Defaults to false in development mode, and true in production mode. In test mode, the default is false if Spring is installed, true otherwise.